# Galaxies moving relative to other galaxies?

Tags: astrophysics, space-expansion, redshift

I've been going through "Astrophysics in a Nutshell" for a college course. I'm not asking for an answer to a problem - but the author makes an aside in a problem that confused me.

At the end of a problem regarding angular-diameter distance, he says "an object at high redshift may have been closer to us at the time of emission than an object of the same size at a lower redshift, despite the fact that the high-redshift object is currently more distant".

How is this possible, given the uniform expansion of the universe? Shouldn't everything stay at the same relative distance?

Comment: It's possible because the universe used to be much smaller, (but expanding much faster), so all distances were smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a somewhat convoluted way of describing the fact that galaxies of a given size shrink in angular diameter the farther away they are (as expected), but only out to a certain distance, roughly 15 billion lightyears. After this, they start to *increase* in apparent size. The reason is that when the distant galaxy emitted the light we see today, it was closer to us and hence looked larger. [Here's an illustration](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/8688/5264) on astronomy.SE that may help understand the mechanism.

The figure in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/18361/5264) shows how large an angle an object of one kpc ($\simeq3300$ lightyears) would span. For instance, you see that the galaxies of the same physical size ~5 Gly away and ~28 Gly away would span roughly the same angle on the sky.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the objects started off with different speeds of recession from us.   So the one that was closer was moving at 100 km/s away from us and the one which was further away was moving at 1 km/s away from us.